# Bootstrap - dropdown list items disappearing after I click on the dropdown button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am making an example project for my PHP course, I have a sidebar navigation with 2 dropdown menus. Whenever I click on a dropdown button the list items of that menu keep disappearing. You can see the gif below to see what exactly happens.

[Click here for the gif](http://g.recordit.co/1AJI3YQsnC.gif)

This is the code below, it's only the side navigation. All the other parts like header, footer and content are in other pages and have been included in the index file using include() function of PHP.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
 <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">CMS Admin</a>
 </div>
 <!-- Top Menu Items -->
 <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">                            
    <li><a href="../index.php">Visit Website</a></li>                                                
    <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
   <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
    {   
     echo $_SESSION['username'];
    }
   ?>
   <b class="caret"></b></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li>
     <a href="../includes/logout.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>                        
 <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
   <li>
    <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#posts_dropdown"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sticky-note"></i>Posts <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <ul id="posts_dropdown" class="collapse">
     <li>
      <a href="./posts.php"> View All Posts</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="posts.php?source=add_post">Add Posts</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="./cats.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sitemap"></i> Categories</a>
   </li>

   <li class="">
    <a href="comments.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comments"></i> Comments</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-users"></i> Users <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
     <li>
      <a href="users.php">View All Users</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="users.php?source=add_user">Add User</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>

   <li>
    <a href="profile.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user-circle-o"></i> Profile</a>
   </li>                                                          
  </ul>
 </div>
 <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Looks like a CSS issue because your code example does not have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your script and link tags, it works fine, here a short example of your code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
 <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">CMS Admin</a>
 </div>
 <!-- Top Menu Items -->                    
 <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
   <li>
    <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#posts_dropdown"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sticky-note"></i>Posts <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <ul id="posts_dropdown" class="collapse">
     <li>
      <a href="./posts.php"> View All Posts</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="posts.php?source=add_post">Add Posts</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-users"></i> Users <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
     <li>
      <a href="users.php">View All Users</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="users.php?source=add_user">Add User</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>

   <li>
    <a href="profile.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user-circle-o"></i> Profile</a>
   </li>                                                          
  </ul>
 </div>
 <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Comment: I am getting this error in the console :                                                                              
    "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js 
   (https://popper.js.org)
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6"

Comment: I noticed something strange. At first the bootstrap version which was being used was v3.2.2 then I downloaded the v4.0.0-beta Bootstrap files and js files which created issues with the project (like bootstrap not loading) so I replaced the Bootstrap and js files with the default v3.2.2 which came along with the project files when I downloaded it. Now when I view the source of the bootstrap.min.js file its showing that the version is v4.0.0-beta but the bootstrap.min.css file is v3.2.2